# PHP anonymous function within class method hides class name (would like to use something like self to address the class name)

Tags: php, oop, methods, functional-programming, classname

In the PHP code below a line of code has been commented out (see the comments) and replaced with the next one, with the intention of achieving the same effect without specifying the class name. However, the explicit class name which I am trying to eliminate in my code is hidden from the function. How can I fix this without explicitly writing down the class name as in the original code?

```
class EmbeddedTriplets {

  private $count;

  private $values;

  function __construct($value = 0, $count = 1) {

    $this->count = $count;

    $this->values = array($value, $value, $value);

  }

  public function getEmbeddedOutput() {

    if ($this->count > 0) {

      $output = $this->values;

      $func = function($value) {

        //return new EmbeddedTriplets($value);
        // HERE INSTEAD OF THE LINE ABOVE I WOULD LIKE TO WRITE ACHIEVE THE SAME THING
        // BUT WITHOUT SPECIFYING THE CLASS NAME (SO THAT IF THE CLASS NAME CHANGES THEN
        // I WILL ONLY NEED TO CHANGE IT IN ONE PLACE IN THE CODE, i.e. next to the class keyword).
        return new self($value);

      };

      for ($i = 0; $i < $this->count - 1; $i++) {

         $output = array_map($func, $output);

      }

      return $output;

    }

    return null;

  }

}

$et = new EmbeddedTriplets(10, 3);
print_r($et->getEmbeddedOutput());
```

OUTPUT:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active on line <b>25</b><br />
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
        (
            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
        (
            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
        (
            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => EmbeddedTriplets Object
                        (
                            [count:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => 1
                            [values:EmbeddedTriplets:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 10
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `__CLASS__` constant:

```
$class = __CLASS__;
return new $class($value);
```

As of PHP 5.5.0 you can use `class`:

```
$class = self::class;
```

Still no one-liner as far as I know.

Comment: Would it also be possible to do the same thing with a one-liner? `return new __CLASS__($value);` doesn't work. Is there another solution. I don't want to have to create that extra variable if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure no, but maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: Let's wait and see. If nobody comes up with anything then I'll accept your answer (would have been nice if PHP implemented an equivalent of `call_user_func()` named `new_instance()` or something. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a grammar problem (the PHP grammar is not allowing a constant where we would like to use it).

Comment: No, because once you are in the closure, you are out of the class scope (not in the class anymore).  All functions in a php file essentially get "pulled" to the top level.  You have to store the class in a variable and pass it in. Also note, `__CLASS__` happens at compilation time, where self::class happens at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a better solution (it actually uses more lines of code), but it shows how such functions can also be coded to use class instances:

```
class EmbeddedTriplets {

  private $count;

  private $values;

  private $class;

  function __construct($value = 0, $count = 1) {

    $this->count = $count;

    $this->values = array($value, $value, $value);

    $this->class = __CLASS__;

  }

  public function getEmbeddedOutput() {

    if ($this->count > 0) {

      $output = $this->values;

      $class = $this->class;

      $func = function($value) use ($class) {

        return new $class($value);

      };

      for ($i = 0; $i < $this->count - 1; $i++) {

         $output = array_map($func, $output);

      }

      return $output;

    }

    return null;

  }

}

$et = new EmbeddedTriplets(10, 3);
print_r($et->getEmbeddedOutput());
```